# Correct term for non-countersunk flat hex screw/ bolt?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bolting

There is a type of screw/ bolt that is flat on top so that it's almost flush when fully seated, but it is *not* counter-sunk, and it usually takes a hex driver (allen key). I see it used on Ikea furniture frequently, and the only pic I could find of it was from an Ikea manual:

[image]

Note that it is not counter-sunk so from the side it looks like a 'T'.

Does anyone know what the correct mech eng jargon term for this screw would be? E.g. if I'm telling someone to switch from a pan-head to this type of screw?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call that a wafer head machine screw.

Answer (score 2):

"Low-profile cap head bolt" would describe it also.  Googling that returns images like
[image]

but the accepted answer is technically correct.